# HTML5 -webkit-transition doesn't work if I set it right before setting something else using javascript on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, classname, webkit-transition

I'm still new to HTML5 but I faced a very strange behavior. (In Chrome)

The following code works on chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Webkit-transition test</title>
    <script language="javascript" >
        function addSpan()
        {
            document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML = "<span id=\"t47\" >A new span!</span>";
            document.getElementById("t47").className += "letter";
        }
        function moveIt()
        {
            document.getElementById("t47").style["MozTransform"] = "translate(10px,40px)";
            document.getElementById("t47").style["WebkitTransform"] = "translate(10px,40px)";
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .letter{
            -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            display: inline-block;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="someDiv"></div>
<span class="letter"  id="aaa">This is an old span</span>
<button onclick='addSpan()'>Add Span</button>
<button onclick='moveIt()'>Move it!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

However if I move the line:

```
document.getElementById("t47").className += "letter";
```

to the beginning of the moveIt function, the span just jumps without transitioning

The javascript part would be like this:

```
<script language="javascript" >
    function addSpan()
    {
        document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML = "<span id=\"t47\" >A new span!</span>";

    }
    function moveIt()
    {
        document.getElementById("t47").className += "letter";
        document.getElementById("t47").style["MozTransform"] = "translate(10px,40px)";
        document.getElementById("t47").style["WebkitTransform"] = "translate(10px,40px)";
    }
</script>
```

So What is the difference here? These two cases work well on firefox though. I haven't tried IE.

I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Why do you need to add the `letter` in the `moveIt` function?  Is it going to do any harm if it's there all the time?

Comment: Well, this is just an example of my problem. In the original code I'm writing, I have to set the class to the element just before I translate it, which currently doesn't work. They don't transition.

Comment: Oh, and if you mean to add class="letter" when I first make the span, like this:
"<span id=\"t47\" class\"letter\" >A new span!</span>"
This doesn't work too. Even the color doesn't change as if it doesn't apply the class. So I could only get that to work by adding it by javasscript.. and then I faced this problem >.>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the CSS Transitions specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/):

> ... changing any of the transition properties a small amount of time after making a change that might transition can result in behavior that varies between implementations, since the changes might be considered simultaneous in some implementations but not others.

In your alternative version, you change the `className` and update the `transform` without allowing the browser to calculate the consequences of the change to the `className`. (This typically happens when you return control to the event loop.) Therefore, the browser may still be operating from the old value of the `transition` property (which is the default value of `all 0s ease 0s`). If that occurs, then the property change takes place immediately with no animation since the delay and duration are `0s`.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that! Interesting~
Hmm, so it applies the change of the class After it applies the change of the transition property? Although I called the change of class first?

Well, any idea how to solve this? I'm doing this:
`for (var k in grandHash) {
     if (grandHash.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
         document.getElementById(k).className += "letter";
        }
    }
for (var k in grandHash) {
       if (grandHash.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
document.getElementById(k).style["WebkitTransform"]= grandHash[k];
     }
}
`
This also doesn't work, although there is time between the changes.

Comment: It's not a question of elapsed time. It's a question of when you give the browser a chance to calculate the consequences of your change to `className`. Sure, you changed `className` but the consequences of that change (looking up the styles, applying cascading, inheritance, etc.) haven't been determined yet. Your code is doing calculation the whole time and doesn't give the browser a chance to do its own calculations.

Comment: Thanks a lot! after your comment, I let the function that is currently running end to give some time for the browser. before the function ends, I added setTimeout(applyTransitions(),1) which well run after 1 millisecond, but after allowing the browser to process the changes, and it worked =D You saved the rest of my hair (from being pulled out!)