# CSS3 animate or transition elements into position after removal of an element above

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

What is the best way of achieving this without any visible flickering and any wierdness?

The fiddle to start out: http://jsfiddle.net/35qec14b/2/

```js
$('.element').on('click', function(e){
  this.remove();
});
```

```css
.element {
  position:relative;
  width: 200px;
  margin:5px;
  padding:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
  background: rgb(150,200,250);
  transition:1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
(click to remove)
<div class="element">Element 1</div>
<div class="element">Element 2<br>Second line</div>
<div class="element">Element 3</div>
<div class="element">Element 4<br>Second line</div>
<div class="element">Element 5</div>
```

*Note: the removed element must disappear instantly in this case, as it would appear in another location and we don't want it to be visible in two places simultaneously.*

Ideas so far:

- **transform:translateY** for ALL elements below the removed one (probably performance intensive for large lists)
- Animate/transform **margin** of the first element below, from *removed element's height* to 0 (leveraging chained animations? step-start?)
- Replace the removed element with a transparent placeholder and animate it's own **height** to 0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best that comes to mind is to hide it, clone it for its new location (not showed here), and then animate its height

When one animate both margins, paddings and height, it becomes not so smooth, so I added an extra inner wrapper for the content so the animation only animates the height

```js
$('.element').on('click', function(e) {
  this.style.height = $(this).height()+ 'px';
  this.classList.add('hide-me');
  (function(el) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.remove();
    }, 500);
  })(this);
});
```

```css
.element {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.element > div {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgb(150, 200, 250);
}

.element.hide-me {
  animation: hideme .5s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}
@keyframes hideme {
  100% {
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
(click to remove)
<div class="element">
  <div>
    Element 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="element">
  <div>
    Element 2
    <br>Second line
  </div>
</div>
<div class="element">
  <div>
    Element 3
  </div>
</div>
<div class="element">
  <div>
    Element 4
    <br>Second line
  </div>
</div>
<div class="element">
  <div>
    Element 5
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks LGSon. I see some kind of very fast flickering on the elements and the scrollbar. Do you think it can be reliably prevented with this approach?

Comment: No, but I think I isolated the problem by setting animations timing to higher values: https://jsfiddle.net/usdut3um/2/

Comment: Animation is smooth in the /3 version, but the smoothness fix relies on fixed height, which cannot be fixed in my case. Nevertheless, I will try to play around with your approach. I think if I will replace the removed item with a placeholder by JS (in my case the element will be dragged out, so it can't wait for the animation) then the flickering should be solved.

Comment: @Alph.Dev I made another version, setting height dynamically, though it doesn't work and here is why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619998/html5-webkit-transition-doesnt-work-if-i-set-it-right-before-setting-something

Comment: @Alph.Dev Figured it out ... to use `animation` instead of `transition` ... updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

Here's the jQuery approach using `.animate()`

```js
$('.element').on('click', function(e){
  var $this = $(this), $next = $this.next();
  $next.css({
    marginTop: $this.outerHeight(true)
  }).animate({
    marginTop: 5
  }, 200);
  $this.remove();
});
```

```css
.element {
  position:relative;
  width: 200px;
  margin:5px;
  padding:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
  background: rgb(150,200,250);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
(click to remove)
<div class="element">Element 1</div>
<div class="element">Element 2<br>Second line</div>
<div class="element">Element 3</div>
<div class="element">Element 4<br>Second line</div>
<div class="element">Element 5</div>
```

And here is a CSS transition approach

```js
$('.element').on('click', function(e){
  var $this = $(this), $next = $this.next();
  $next.css({
    marginTop: $this.outerHeight(true)
  });
  setTimeout(()=>{
    $next.addClass('hide');
    setTimeout(()=>{
      $next.css({marginTop: ''}).removeClass('hide');
    }, 250)
  }, 20);
  $this.remove();
});
```

```css
.element {
  position:relative;
  width: 200px;
  margin:5px;
  padding:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
  background: rgb(150,200,250);
}

.element.hide {
  transition: margin-top 0.25s linear;
  margin-top: 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
(click to remove)
<div class="element">Element 1</div>
<div class="element">Element 2<br>Second line</div>
<div class="element">Element 3</div>
<div class="element">Element 4<br>Second line</div>
<div class="element">Element 5</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing two approaches side by side. The one using `transition:margin-top` doesn't animate on my browser, can you look into it please?

Comment: @Alph.Dev What browser are you using?  It could be the ecmascript 6 arrow functions or it could be that `transition` needs prefixed, but it's too difficult to tell without know what browser and version you're using.

Comment: It works in Chrome 59, but FF 54 gives unexpected results. The wierd thing is, sometimes it animates in FF too, but most of the time there is no smooth animation. Just a jump.

Comment: @Alph.Dev Looks like  it might be my poor-man's request animation frame.  It's probably better to just use raq, but for compatibility, I just added a 20ms value to  the first timeout. See if that works in FF54.

Comment: That did the trick! Can you explain whats happening there? Why did it lag, and why did adding timeout help?

Comment: 1) @Alph.Dev It's there because we set the margin using an inline style and immediately change the class.  If this is done at the same time, it doesn't trigger the transition because it sees the animation as already complete.  We add the timeout to force a repaint before we change the class.  That forces the animation to trigger.  I changed it to [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), which does the same thing more explicitly.  Originally I used timeout because it has slightly better compatibility, but I don't think that's...

Comment: 2) as much of an issue anymore.  requestanimationframe has [much better compatibility now](http://caniuse.com/#search=requestanimationframe).

Comment: @Alph.Dev I had to rollback that change.  requestanimationframe isn't quite working in FF for some reason.  Either way the timeout has the same effect, so it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are concerned that using transforms could have a negative performance, I think that the opposite is true.

Bear in mind that other solutions involve massive reflows, that probably are more performance intensive on the CPU (transforms most probably are handled by the GPU).

However, solving this with this with transforms is a little bit hard to code. Specially changing the amount of pixels that need to be moved, and injecting them into the style.

See a posible solution. I have used just JS to make it more portable.

If you are concern about performance, the result of findKeyframesRule could be assigned to a variable and reused.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setEvent, false);

function setEvent() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('element');

  for (var n = 0; n < elements.length; n++) {
    elements[n].addEventListener('click', remove, false);
  }
}

function remove(event) {
  var current = event.currentTarget;
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('move');
  for (var n = 0; n < elements.length; n++) {
    elements[n].classList.remove('move');
  }
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    remove2(current);
  }, 0);
}

function remove2(current) {
  var next = current.nextElementSibling;
  if (!next) {
    return;
  }
  var top1 = current.offsetTop;
  var top2 = next.offsetTop;
  var diff = top2 - top1;
  var newTransform = 'translateY(' + diff + 'px)';

  var rule = findKeyframesRule('move');
  var style = rule.cssRules[0].style;
  style.transform = newTransform;
  next.classList.add('move');
  current.style.height = '0px';
}

function findKeyframesRule(rule) {
  // gather all stylesheets into an array
  var ss = document.styleSheets;

  // loop through the stylesheets
  for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {

    var ss1 = ss[i];
    // loop through all the rules
    if (!ss1.cssRules) {
      alert('you are using Chrome in local files');
      return null;
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < ss1.cssRules.length; j++) {

      // find the keyframe rule whose name matches our passed parameter
      if (ss1.cssRules[j].type == window.CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE && ss1.cssRules[j].name == rule)
        return ss1.cssRules[j];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

```css
.element {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.element>div {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgb(150, 200, 250);
}

.move,
.move~.element {
  animation: move 2s;
}

@keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: translateY(60px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY( 0px);
  }
}
```

```html
(click to remove)
<div class="element">
  <div>
    Element 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="element">
  <div>
    Element 2
    <br>Second line
  </div>
</div>
<div class="element">
  <div>
    Element 3
  </div>
</div>
<div class="element">
  <div>
    Element 4
    <br>Second line
  </div>
</div>
<div class="element">
  <div>
    Element 5
  </div>
</div>
```